# How to mock CSV foreach method in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a method that uses CSV.foreach method.
The data should look like that:

`1,0,0,1`

`1,1,0,0`

I want to write a test which expects an error if I the number of elements is not the same in each line.

Something like:

```
it "should raise an error if input file lines size differ" do
  expect { my_method(invalid_file_name) }.to raise_error
end
```

How do I mock CSV's foreach method to return invalid input?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can indeed stub CSV's `foreach` method, but you need to use the `and_yield` method and chaining to generate more than one line, to wit:

```
CSV.stub(:foreach).and_yield(<first_line>).and_yield(<second_line)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the and_yield part.

Answer (score -2):

You can do

```
CSV.stub(:foreach).and_retuen(<invalid_output>)
```

Its just like stubbing any other method.